# interference of SPView SPQueries

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

my problem is i have multiple users who do connect to my sharepoint site list. in my standpoint i made some kind of filter on the SPview to show the user only the data related to him. but the problem when user connect get view whith his data, the problem is when the next user connect get the view with data of the connected user.

```
  list = site.list["listname"];
  Spveiw v = list.views["allItems"];

 if(user1){

   SPQuery query0 = new SPQuery();
   query0.Query = "my camel query for user1";
   v.Query = query0.Query;
   v.Update();
   list.Update();  

 }else if(user2){

   PQuery query1 = new SPQuery();
   query1.Query = "my camel query for user2";
   v.Query = query1.Query;
   v.Update();
   list.Update(); 

  }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? This code looks really strange (not the code, but the purpose of it)

Comment: it does work perfectly

Comment: I'm not doubting that it is compiling and doing its job. But what you are actually doing here is updating the actual view everytime one of the two users above logs in. Would it not be better to either filter on "<Me />" or to create different views and then in an XSLTListViewWebpart select the aprropriate view based on user?

Comment: i'm using that in HttpModule

Comment: What difference does that make? ;) You are still doing something very strange in your code snippet, and I do not understand from your question description what you are having trouble with and what the real objective is

Comment: if the first user connect get his view filtered by his spquery (spquery0), the problem is when the second user connect got the view filtered by spquery0 and not by spquery1